# How to make a ViewFlipper which displays three views at once?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I would like to do something like in the picture

[image]

Comment: ViewFlipper only allows two views to shown. Try looking into ViewPager instead.

Comment: Check ViewPager, it's a builtin android component.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, can you please share your experience if you found any solution? thx

Answer (score 1):

Use `ViewFlipper` and create custom `FragmentPageAdapter`